# What is http://LnxRelease-02/deb in Software and updates -> Other software?

Tags: apt, software-sources, teamviewer

This might have something to do with TeamViewer, because i have it installed and have found it mentioned on the internet with it.

But still, http://LnxRelease-02/deb doesn't look like a real web domain - so what's going on here?

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu desktop 20.04 focal fossa

EDIT 2: Here is an image of the issue:
[image: Screenshot of LnxRelease inside Software updates]

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Where did you find this `http://LnxRelease-02/deb`?

Comment: This is something wierd and maybe unsafe. It is not related to teamviewr. It is something else.

Comment: This looks like malware to me. I suggest to remove it and re-install the system.

Comment: Well i don't remember installing any unknown softwares, except Signal messenger recently. It used this command, which felt safe for me because i manually downloaded and inspected the .asc file, it was only a private key.
`curl -s https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from TeamViewer.  Whomever built the .deb and .rpm packages incorrectly included their *internal* repository address, instead of the public external repository.

apt, zypper, yum, & etc. will fail as this is not resolvable outside of the TeamViewer internal network.  At least for OpenSuSE, this repo is listed as 'tvinternal.repo'.

I went to the TeamViewer website and just downloaded the latest .rpm package, then uninstalled the old one, and installed the newly downloaded rpm package.

```
{21}# rpm -e `rpm -qa | grep teamviewer`
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/teamviewerd.service.
Clearing assignments ...
done
warning: /etc/zypp/repos.d/tvinternal.repo saved as /etc/zypp/repos.d/tvinternal.repo.rpmsave

{22}# rm /etc/zypp/repos.d/tvinternal.repo.rpmsave

{23}# zypper -v in ./teamviewer-suse_15.5.3.x86_64.rpm
...

{24}# ls /etc/zypp/repos.d/t*.repo
teamviewer.repo
```

Now updates work as expected.

HTH.
--PSK

Comment: I contacted their support long ago, there was no reply, so accepting this as an answer.